# How to efficiently listen to multiple events and how to structure application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, three.js, webgl

I am currently planing quite a complex web application (`WebGL - Three.JS`) and I am experimenting with a few tests right now. The problem I stumbled upon is rising a lot of questions for me and I don't know a correct way to do it and I would really appreciate if anyone could point me to the right direction.

So here is the thing:
My applications needs a lot of event listeners and It needs to be as modular as possible. So that I can remove something without breaking everything.

With events listeners I mean, that I need to check If user clicked on element, if element is selected, If it is, change tools view,... Pretty complex. I will also develope a few tools (`Cloning, mirroring,..`) and I can clearly see that with functions I won't be able to do it efficently and my code will get VERY MESSY. Or for example; If users select "`cube draw`" control, I need to lock some of the controls, and then listen for the click event,.. But the problem is, how do ižI structure so many different click events?

*Actually I draw a simple sketch what I need:*
[image]

Also, so that you won't think I am lazy, I've written a simple example of what I need with pure Javascript functions,.. It's already buggy, sphagheti and I don't think it's the right way. It has to be another way right?

My attemp:
[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zaay/Q7tbb/1/)

I am looking for something like: http://shapesmith.net/, but it's written with Backbone and so many different files that I cannot get a clue how it's made.

Answer (score 0):

add your domelement to the trackballcontrol.. so that the click event made on renderer portion will identify by trackball control...

```
controls = new THREE.TrackballControls( camera, renderer.domElement );
```